# Reduce multiple if else statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following 5 variables to check for a condition.

**Example**:

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col2 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col3 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col4 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col5 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX)


IF @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = ''
BEGIN
    SET @String = ''
END
ELSE IF @Col1 <> '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = ''
BEGIN
    SET @String = '@Col1'
END
ELSE IF @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 <> '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = ''
BEGIN
    SET @String = '@Col2'
END
ELSE IF @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 <> '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = ''
BEGIN
    SET @String = '@Col3'
END
ELSE IF @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 <> '' AND @Col5 = ''
BEGIN
    SET @String = '@Col4'
END
.....
.....
.....
```

As the above conditions show, there are many probabilities.

How can I reduce the occurrences of multiple if conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT @String = CASE
                    WHEN @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = ''  THEN ''
                    WHEN @Col1 <> '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = '' THEN '@Col1'
                    WHEN @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 <> '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = '' THEN '@Col2'
                    WHEN @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 <> '' AND @Col4 = '' AND @Col5 = '' THEN '@Col3'
                    WHEN @Col1 = '' AND @Col2 = '' AND @Col3 = '' AND @Col4 <> '' AND @Col5 = '' THEN '@Col4'
                    ELSE NULL
                END
```

SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT @String = COALESCE(IIF(@Col1 <> '', '@Col1', NULL),
                          IIF(@Col2 <> '', '@Col2', NULL),
                          IIF(@Col3 <> '', '@Col3', NULL),
                          IIF(@Col4 <> '', '@Col4',  '' ));
```

**EDIT:**

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col2 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col3 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col4 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col5 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

IF @col1 <> ''
   SET @String += '@col1';

IF @col2 <> ''
   SET @String += '@col2';

IF @col3 <> ''
   SET @String += '@col3';

...

IF @coln <> ''
   SET @String += '@coln';
```

Comment: Is that possible without using `CASE`?

Comment: @MAK Why don't you like `CASE`?

Comment: **For downvoters you can specify what is wrong with this solution**

Comment: Because as I said in my question! there are many probabilities. Like if there are possibility `@Col1` and `@Col2` are not empty or other multiple columns are not empty. There are many probabilities.

Comment: @MAK define in your question what to do when Col1 and col2 are not empty, do you want concatenation of them?

Comment: Yes! exactly. If any columns are not empty then it should get concatenate.

Comment: And I need to inform you that I have not down voted your post.

Comment: Yup! This is what I was looking for. +1 for that is sure. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MAK Happy I can help, for future make more explicit question.

Comment: @lad2025, Sure! Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help as well, sorry for a different approach.
I took your case as something that can be stacked and I arrived at this.

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(10) = 'test'
DECLARE @Col2 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col3 VARCHAR(10) = 'tet'
DECLARE @Col4 VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @Col5 VARCHAR(10) = 't'
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #cols (ColName NVARCHAR(150), ColVal NVARCHAR(150))

INSERT INTO #cols VALUES ('@Col1',@Col1),('@Col2',@Col2),('@Col3',@Col3),('@Col4',@Col4),('@Col5',@Col5)

-- if you want to just concatenate things without a delimiter, you can do this
SET @String = (SELECT ColName AS [text()] FROM #cols WHERE ColVal != '' FOR XML PATH(''))

SELECT @String
-- output @Col1@Col3@Col5

-- if you want to concatenate things with a delimiter, you can do this
SET @String = (SELECT ColName + ', ' AS [text()] FROM #cols WHERE ColVal != '' FOR XML PATH(''))

SELECT @String
-- output @Col1, @Col3, @Col5

DROP TABLE #cols
```

Hope this adds something to the idea. Please let me know if you have concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in one statement using `case expressions`:

```
SELECT @String = CASE WHEN @Col1 = '' THEN 'col1' ELSE '' END +
                 CASE WHEN @Col2 = '' THEN 'col2' ELSE '' END +
                 CASE WHEN @Col3 = '' THEN 'col3' ELSE '' END +
                 CASE WHEN @Col4 = '' THEN 'col4' ELSE '' END +
                 CASE WHEN @Col5 = '' THEN 'col5' ELSE '' END
```